# Use a image as a nav bar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am looking to create a pretty standard responsive nav bar but I would like to use an image as the background ( which is also responsive ). I can't seem to find any bootstrap tutorials or information on this. Does anybody know how it can be achieved?

here is the image:

[Nav bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXbyJ.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: you need to at least have a try at doing something rather than asking "Spoon feed me".

Comment: I have tried creating a nav with a container-fluid inside and filling the container with a responsive image. However the image resizes to different proportions to the actual nav.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting background image of a navigation bar - bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29619346/setting-background-image-of-a-navigation-bar-bootstrap)

Answer (score 2):

Using this example: [Navbar Template for Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/)

You can do something like:

```
.navbar {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXbyJ.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Here, `background-size:cover` allows the image to resize proportionally while covering the entire navbar.

Then, to have a different background for small screens, you can use media queries:

```
.navbar {
    background: #60c7c6;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar {
        background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXbyJ.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sesn/yuggfay3/

```
.navbar-header { background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXbyJ.jpg); background-size: cover; }
```